# How to Generate POJO for an SQL View Using Scripted Extensions

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, sql-view

Is it possible to generate POJOs for an SQL Views using Scripted Extensions?

(I am able to generate POJOs for Tables, just fine. But Views and up having to variables/columns.)

Answer (score 0):

Thios can not be done yet, please vote/comment for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4115